# Is there a way to untar a file and merge all the extracted files into one for efficient R data analysis?

Tags: r, tar

I know how to untar a file, but I want to keep all of the infomation into one file not 12 different files after it is untar'ed. I use a MacBook.

I want to compute the data into R so I need the untared files to be in one file. Or will R analyze many files and imput it into one table once the metadata is run. I have the latest version of RStudio

Answer (score 0):

With {[vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/)} you can conveniently read in text files into one combined dataframe like so:

```
library(vroom)
vroom(list.files('path/to/your/untarred/files', full.names = TRUE),
             id = 'source' ## optional: keep file names in column 'source'
      )
```